# Does the existence of a minimal cover for a subset of reals need some form of choice?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In Kanamori's book, "The Higher Infinite" p. 376, he defines a *minimal cover* of some $A \subseteq \omega^\omega$, to be any $B \subseteq \omega^\omega$, such that $A\subseteq B$ and that $B$ is Lebesgue measurable and if $Z \subseteq B-A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $m_L(Z) = 0$. And he claims that picking some $B$ with $A\subseteq B$ and $m_L(B)$ minimal, does the job. [Here $m_L$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.]

Now here is my problem. The whole premise of this chapter is that we don't want to use choice to do these things. But any way I try to construct such a $B$, I inevitably use some form of choice. The best I can do is $\mathsf{AC}_\omega(\omega^\omega)$. Is there some choice-free way to do this?

---

A sketch of a proof with $\mathsf{AC}_\omega(\omega^\omega)$: Let $x = \inf\{m_L(B): A\subseteq B \text{ and } B \text{ is Lebesgue measurable}\}$. By $\mathsf{AC}_\omega(\omega^\omega)$, let $\langle B_n: n<\omega\rangle$ be a sequence such that $A\subseteq B_n$ and $m_L(B_n) \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Now $B = \bigcap_n B_n$ is the desired minimal cover. $\square$

Comment: Measure theory without at the very least $\sf AC_\omega(\Bbb R)$ is nothing short of terrifying.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I guess so. :) And since we are working with $\mathsf{AD}$ and we already have $\mathsf{AC}_\omega(\omega^\omega)$, I don't think there is any critical issue in the text. I was just wondering if I was missing something trivial. Because the book says in the beginning of this chapter that any use of $\mathsf{AC}$ will be explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Well. How do you define the Lebesgue (or even Borel) measure in the Feferman–Levy model?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I don't think defining the measures on the Borel and Lebesgue sigma algebras needs choice, does it? I don't know. I'll need to review my analysis books.

Comment: Okay, another question, what is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Well, if we want to go with the classical route, it is the intersection of all the sigma algebras containing the open subsets. But I can see how the recursive definition might become troublesome.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri In ZF alone that could be the full powerset of the reals. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638461/there-is-a-sigma1-1-universal-set-and-this-is-not-borel-where-did-we-use-th/3638572#3638572).

Comment: So in the Feferman–Levy model, where every set of reals is a countable union of countable sets, how do you define a measure on the Borel sets which is both countably additive and non-trivial?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, yes. But that still wouldn't be a problem, would it? We still can go on and do our analysis I guess.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Well it means for example that measure isn't countably additive anymore.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Oh, I get it now. That's a grim situation. :) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Thanks for the great link!

Comment: Just to clarify, now that you're aware of the horrors of measure theory without countable choice, do you want to clarify your question (or delete it altogether)?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, since my issue is resolved and maybe in the future this might be a question for someone else, and because of the effort put into the comments, I would prefer if you could write an answer and I would accept it, so it would be off of the unanswered list. If not, I can post an answer myself. Or if maybe none of the options are okay, I can delete it.

Comment: I'd normally opt for one of us (you, @Noah, me) to write an answer. But since the comments sort of clarify that the idea is somehow problematic to begin with, I'd actually go with deleting. But it's up to you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, since I think there is something to be learned here(in the comments)(at least for someone like me), I am reluctant to delete it. Since you have already notified Noah Schweber, if you guys won't want to post an answer, I will try to post one based on the comments, until tomorrow night. I hope this is okay with everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in fact a theorem of ZF. The Caratheodory construction of Lebesgue measure works in ZF, though without choice it need not be $\sigma$-additive. Every Borel codable set of reals is measurable but not necessarily every Borel set. See the paper cited below.

Let $U_i$ enumerate the basic open sets of $\omega^{\omega}.$ By (finite) subadditivity of $\lambda^*$ and adjusting the proof of the Lebesgue density theorem, we have that for any $X$ with $\lambda^*(X)>0$ and $\epsilon >0,$ there is $U_i$ such that $\lambda^*(X \cap U_i) > (1-\epsilon) \lambda(U_i).$

Define $S_n$ recursively by having $i \in S_n$ if $\lambda^*(A \cap U_i \setminus \bigcup_{j<i, j \in S_n} U_j)>\frac{n-1}{n} \lambda(U_i).$ Let $V_n = \bigcup_{i \in S_n} U_i$ and $V = \bigcap_{n<\omega} V_n.$

By our density lemma, each $A \setminus V_n$ is null. Since $\lambda^*$ is additive among subsets of disjoint measurable sets, we have

$$\lambda(V_n) - \frac{1}{n} \le
\frac{n-1}{n}\lambda(V_n) \le \sum_{i \in S_n} \lambda^*\left (A \cap U_i \setminus \bigcup_{j<i, j \in S_n} U_j \right ) \le \lambda^*(A) \le \lambda^*(A \cup V_n) =\lambda(V_n).$$

We compute
$$\lambda^*(A \setminus V) \le \inf_{n<\omega} \left ( \lambda^*\left (\bigcap_{i<n} V_n \setminus V \right ) + \lambda^*\left (A \setminus \bigcap_{i<n} V_n \right ) \right ) =0.$$

Therefore, $B := A \cup V$ is measurable, with

$$\lambda^*(A) \le \lambda(B) = \lambda(V) \le \inf_{n<\omega} \lambda(V_n)
\le \inf_{n<\omega} \left (\lambda^*(A) + \frac{1}{n} \right) = \lambda^*(A).$$
So $B$ is as desired.

*Foreman, Matthew; Wehrung, Friedrich*, [**The Hahn-Banach theorem implies the existence of a non-Lebesgue measurable set**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm-138-1-13-19), Fundam. Math. 138, No. 1, 13-19 (1991). [ZBL0792.28005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0792.28005).

Comment: This is very cool, thanks! So in light of the other answer, the usual notions of real analysis seem to malfunction in the absence of choice. I'm wondering to what extent do the usual theorems and "definitions" go through in this setting; like the one you showed above. Would you know if there a systematic account of this available?

Comment: Fremlin's Measure Theory Vol. 5 goes into the measure theory of Borel-codable sets. Most of concrete measure theory has choiceless analogues in this setting. There isn't much written about what works and what doesn't in choiceless measure theory in more general settings. I'm working on filling that gap. See also this post: https://mathoverflow.net/a/393162/109573

Comment: Oh I see, very nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is purely a compilation of the ideas in the comments, given by Asaf Karagila and Noah Schweber. I have also made this a "Community Wiki", so I won't gain any reputation from any upvotes.

---

The thing is that in choiceless setting, most of our definitions in measure theory either don't make sense, or have different non-equivalent forms. To see an example look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638461/there-is-a-sigma1-1-universal-set-and-this-is-not-borel-where-did-we-use-th/3638572#3638572). And also in certain cases we fail to have a measure on the Borel sets. For example in the Feferman–Levy model every set of reals is a countable union of countable sets and so it is not possible to have a measure on the Borel sets which is both countably additive and non-trivial. This is why some level of choice is required to even get started. And so the use of $\mathsf{AC}_\omega(\omega^\omega)$ in the above proof is justified.